# what is a motion controller card (ni motion controllers ) and its difference to motor driver?

Tags: controller, labview, motion, servo

I have a 400 watt servo motor with a driver which needs some pulses to move the motor and control its speed , it can count the encoder pulses,  includes electronic gears and many thing else .

is the motion controller card  a replacement for the motor driver, or a motion controller card should be used next to the motor driver to create the pulse trains and also read the encoder outputs ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about hardware, not programming. Try [Electrical Engineering](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/) or the National Instruments forums, perhaps.

Comment: I asked this question because I wanted to control a servo motor using Labview programming . but I think you are right , it was a mistake to ask it here .

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about hardware, not programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, a motion controller and a driver are two different things:
[image: MotionArchitecture - National Instruments]

See [here](http://www.ni.com/white-paper/9667/) for an overview from National Instruments.